# Cardinality of the set of functions that maps from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$.

Tags: cardinals

I know that from the other direction, the cardinality of the set of function that maps from  $\{1,2,3\}$ to  $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}=|\mathbb{N}|$, however, I don't know how should I work from the other direction.

Comment: Perhaps $\left|3^{\mathbb N}\right|$ though not usually written that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of functions mapping $X\to Y$ is often denoted $Y^X$. It is known that $|Y^X| = |Y|^{|X|}$.

Comment: I do not know this theorem. Can you show me why is that the case?

Comment: @Charlie for the finite case, this is simply the rule of product.  For each of the $|X|$ elements in $X$, you have $|Y|$ options for what it maps to.  Making $|X|$ such choices you have then $|Y|\times |Y|\times \cdots \times |Y|=|Y|^{|X|}$ total outcomes.  For the infinite case, some more care needs to be taken.

Comment: @Charlie for this case, you should know that the number of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\{1,2\}$ is in direct bijection with the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb N)$.  You should also know a result about the number of functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.  You should then be able to reason that your set lies between these as a superset of the first and as a subset of the second and reach a final conclusion.

Comment: What if both $X$ and $Y$ are empty? There is exactly one mapping $\emptyset \rightarrow \emptyset$. But what is $0^0$?